# How do I know if a monster will attack me on sight?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-x

Some monsters seem to attack on sight while others of the same types are happy to leave me alone. How can I tell what monsters are which?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Additionally to Indigens that attack on sight, there are also those who attack when you get too close; those have a lightning bolt symbol instead of an eye one. Many Indigens have both symbols.

Answer (score 5):

To follow on from Nolonar the lightning symbol actually means "auditory type" where they will attack on sound instead of sight. Chapter 11 page 2 of the in game manual.

Comment: Posts like this are best edited into another post if they don't answer the question on their own.

Answer (score 4):

Some monsters have a red eye shape next to their level. This means that if you are in their line of sight they will attack and you will "Flinch."

Comment: This is not entirely always true - you can reduce monsters lines of sight by being higher level than them, or using BLADE gear.