# Is there any indication which enemies will attack on sight?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

In Xenoblade Chronicles 3, is there a way to identify which enemies will attack on sight?

The past Xenoblade games always had some additional information on the enemy's nameplate to inform you if the enemy would attack based on sight or sound, in a group, etc. (e.g. this thread for Xenoblade 1: https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/960564-xenoblade-chronicles/60354516, or this question for Xenoblade X: [How do I know if a monster will attack me on sight?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/247777/how-do-i-know-if-a-monster-will-attack-me-on-sight)).

However, there doesn't seem to be any of this info for Xenoblade 3 on the enemy nameplate. Am I simply missing some identifier? Is it something that is unlocked later, maybe with the party/traversal skills? Or are the icons identifying these 'attack on sight' monsters just removed from Xenoblade 3?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they removed the sight/sound indicators, unfortunately. If you've played xc1/2 you might have an idea of what enemies do what (I believe they're the same), but that is nowhere near as useful.

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. I actually saw later on how they shifted some info around (when an enemy will attack in a group, little arrows show above that group when you target one member), I also still found no indication anywhere else (target cursor/other HUD info) where this would be.

Comment: @Seiyria You ought to post this as an answer

Comment: @Stevoisiak I absolutely can, but it feels completely insubstantial (which is why I left it as a comment).